# Call Action in C++

Tags: c#, c++, action, threadpool

I need to listen to http requests in some old c++ legacy Code. In c# I would be using the following code to listen to http requests:

```
var listener = new HttpListener();
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:8080/");
listener.Start();
while (true)
{
  var ctx = listener.GetContext();
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(() =>
  {
    // do something with ctx.Request
  });
}
```

Now I need to do this in managed C++ - but I got no idea how to do this in C++:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(() =>
{
  // do something with ctx.Request
});
```

The class I'm running this all in is not managed, I use `gcroot<>` to remember the listener als class member.

Comment: if you describe what you want to do this question would be useful also to someone not proficient in both languages

Comment: If you want to make anonymous function, you can use lambda expression.

Comment: @Rhathin how would that look like in c++??

Comment: You wouldn't use `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` in C# either. Why don't you use `Task.Run`? In any case it looks like your question is how to [use lambdas in Managed C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293599.aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_7)

Comment: @Sam simplest implementation will look like this: `[](){ /*Do something... */}`. However, I recommend you to look into [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) to read more about.